# Copy folder tree in Drive API with Python

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, google-drive-api

Aim: copy Google Drive folder tree (including sub-folders and files) from template folder and paste them into new folder.

Problems: Drive API doesn't let you copy folders.

Potential workaround: I have listed a directory tree of the template folder which I can use as a framework.

More problems: I'm having issues writing code to walk through my directory tree and create a new folder tree based on that framework.

Potential solutions: A recursive function that walks through each node of the tree and creates a folder based off of the information (folder name, parent folder, mimeType).

More problems: I've only been coding for a few months and I don't really know how I'd approach a recursive function to achieve this.

Structure of my folder tree below:

```
filesAndFolders = {'childrenFolders': [{'childrenFiles': [{'id': 'Sub-Folder 1 Sub-File 1 ID',
                                                           'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet',
                                                           'name': 'Sub-Folder 1 Sub-File 1'}],
                                        'folderId': 'SUB-FOLDER 1 ID',
                                        'folderName': 'Sub-Folder 1',
                                        'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'},
                                       {'folderId': 'SUB-FOLDER 2 ID',
                                        'folderName': 'Sub-Folder 2',
                                        'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'},
                                       {'childrenFiles': [{'id': 'SUB-FOLDER 3 SUB-FILE 1 ID',
                                                           'mimeType': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
                                                           'name': 'Sub-Folder 3 Sub-File 1'}],
                                        'childrenFolders': [{'folderId': 'SUB-FOLDER 3 SUB-FOLDER 1 ID',
                                                             'folderName': 'Sub-Folder 3 Sub-Folder 1',
                                                             'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'}],
                                        'folderId': 'SUB-FOLDER 3 ID',
                                        'folderName': 'Sub-Folder 3',
                                        'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'}]
                   'folderId': 'TEMPLATE FOLDER ID',
                   'folderName': 'Template Folder',
                   'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'}
```

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far?

Comment: I haven’t got any yet as I really don’t know the first way to approach this. Apologies.